# How to tweak ICU's UnicodeString::caseCompare (or get the same effect)

Tags: c++, unicode, icu

I'm not super familiar with how case-folding/case-insensitive comparisons work, and ICU in general.

Right now, we have some methods that wrap various overloads of `UnicodeString::caseCompare`and I want to change them to do something slightly-different: I want dotted & dotless i's to compare equal (regardless of case).

I know that ICU has a collation API, but I'm not sure how to start off with exactly the same rules as `UnicodeString::caseCompare`, and modify from there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to do this using the C++ UnicodeString class.

You have to drop down to the lower level string-as-an-array-of-UChars functions from [unicode/ustring.h](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ustring_8h.html). In particular, [u_strCaseCompare()](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ustring_8h.html#a56c7ed13d57379ff8b5f0736b0628e09) is probably what you want, or [u_strcasecmp()](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ustring_8h.html#aa610819a5a35df058577f78c68ad0ab0) combined with UnicodeString's [getTerminatedBuffer()](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classicu_1_1UnicodeString.html#ac147028068f109ed48575b1be2585e1e) method.

Documentation for the `U_FOLD_CASE_EXCLUDE_SPECIAL_I` option:

> Use the modified set of mappings provided in CaseFolding.txt to handle dotted I and dotless i appropriately for Turkic languages (tr, az).

I *think* that means to treat them as equivalent.

Edit with actual testing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unicode/ustring.h>
#include <unicode/stringoptions.h>

void comp(const char *a, const char *b) {
  UChar s1[10], s2[10];
  UErrorCode err = U_ZERO_ERROR;
  int32_t len1, len2;
  u_strFromUTF8(s1, 10, &len1, a, -1, &err);
  u_strFromUTF8(s2, 10, &len2, b, -1, &err);
  printf("%s <=> %s: %d (Without special i) %d (With special i)\n", a, b,
         u_strCaseCompare(s1, len1, s2, len2, 0, &err),
         u_strCaseCompare(s1, len1, s2, len2, U_FOLD_CASE_EXCLUDE_SPECIAL_I, &err));
}

int main(void) {
  const char *lc_dotted_i = "i";
  const char *lc_dotless_i = "\u0131";
  const char *uc_dotless_i = "I";
  const char *uc_dotted_i = "\u0130";

  comp(lc_dotted_i, lc_dotless_i);
  comp(uc_dotted_i, uc_dotless_i);
  comp(lc_dotted_i, uc_dotted_i);
  comp(lc_dotless_i, uc_dotless_i);
  comp(lc_dotted_i, uc_dotless_i);
  comp(lc_dotless_i, uc_dotted_i);
  return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
i <=> ı: -200 (Without special i) -200 (With special i)
İ <=> I: 1 (Without special i) -200 (With special i)
i <=> İ: -1 (Without special i) 0 (With special i)
ı <=> I: 200 (Without special i) 0 (With special i)
i <=> I: 0 (Without special i) -200 (With special i)
ı <=> İ: 200 (Without special i) 200 (With special i)
```

Comment: My understanding of that option is that it makes 'normal' i map to capital I with dot, and 'normal' capital I with lowercase I without do

Comment: @Bwmat I whipped up a quick test program and included it and the results in my answer to show actual behavior. (The 0's are the cases where the two characters are considered equal). So not quite what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for testing it out anyhow

Comment: @Bwmat I tried messing with collation and normalization equivalence too, with no luck. Next best suggestion is replacing all non-dotted is with dotted ones (or vis versa) before doing comparisons.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too... But what about combining characters? I think I read somewhere that you can form a dotted I by adding a dot to a dotless I with a combining character, probably need to do some normalization somehow